# Entity Framework Code First - strange behaviour with circular relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm struggling to understand how Code First sets up relationships based on the model. Here's the model:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Nation NationOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Nation CurrentNationOfResidence { get; set; }
}

public class Nation
{
    [Key]
    public string NationName { get; set; }

    public virtual Person CurrentSecondInCommand { get; set; }
}
```

At first I got an error while creating the database, which I was able to solve by adding a couple of modelBuilder commands:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.NationOfBirth)
    .WithRequiredDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.CurrentNationOfResidence)
    .WithRequiredDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And I also added:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Nation>()
    .HasOptional(n => n.CurrentSecondInCommand)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Now when I try and populate my database, with the following code:

```
var america = new Nation { NationName = "America" };
context.Nations.Add(america);
var bush = new Person { PersonName = "Bush", CurrentNationOfResidence = america, NationOfBirth = america };
var obama = new Person { PersonName = "Obama", CurrentNationOfResidence = america, NationOfBirth = america };
var biden = new Person { PersonName = "Biden", CurrentNationOfResidence = america, NationOfBirth = america };
context.People.Add(bush);
context.People.Add(obama);
context.People.Add(biden);
context.SaveChanges();
```

At the point at which 'bush' is added, both the CurrentNationOfResidence and the NationOfBirth properties are not null for him and are set to be the 'america' object. But as soon as 'obama' is added, the CurrentNationOfResidence and the NationOfBirth properties on 'bush' both become null. And the same happens to 'obama' once 'biden' is added.

If I inspect the database that is generated by this, I can't see any foreign key columns created on the People table, but I would have expected Code First to have automatically generated 2 foreign keys for the two Nation fields on Person (that's what I thought my first two modelBuilder commands would do - from the description of "WithRequiredDepedent"). And even more bizarrely there is a single Person called "America" that has been added to the database, as well as a Nation also called America.

I'd really appreciate some advice in general on my model, if anyone can provide it. I realise I have a circular relationship here, but I would have thought that would be ok because Nations aren't required to have a CurrentSecondInCommand. I realise it's a bit complex (or perhaps convoluted is a better word) but I think it makes sense:

- A Person must have a single (Nation) NationOfBirth.
- A Person must have a single (Nation) CurrentNationOfResidence.
- A Nation can optionally have a single (Person) CurrentSecondInCommand.

Any advice would be really welcome, thanks.

Comment: for testing purpose, can you create Nation object like america1, america2 etc and assign to each person and test it

Comment: Also you have to mark NationOfBirth with ForeignKey attribute in person class...

Comment: @Viru Just tried your first suggestion. What happens is that three "People" get added called "America1", "America2" and "America3" (as well as three Nations of the same names).

Comment: @Viru The comment summary for WithRequiredDependent() states that - "The entity type being configured will be the dependent and contain a foreign key to the principal. The entity type that the relationship targets will be the principal in the relationship." - so my understanding was that the foreign keys would be generated by my modelBuilder commands.

Surely one of the advantages of modelling in code is that you don't need to have needless foreign key properties cluttering up the code base. Adding foreign keys everywhere seems inelegant if CF can do (and does) do it for you.

Comment: You are right about WithRequiredDependant. Your problem is not this but that you are configuring one to one relationship while you actually have many to one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two relations from Person to Nation aren't one to one, but many to one:

- A Person must have a single (Nation) NationOfBirth. BUT a Nation has many persons born there
- A Person must have a single (Nation) CurrentNationOfResidence. BUT a Nation has many residents

So your configuration should be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.NationOfBirth)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.CurrentNationOfResidence)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it definitely put me on the right path. I didn't realise my modelBuilder configs were specifying one to one relationships. I've edited the answer to give the configuration needed for the one remaining relationship back to Person to be correct, and marked it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual property in Nation class must be `ICollection<Person> CurrentSecondInCommand`, that way you will have "many persons in one nation" in the database the relationship will be "one to many" not "one to one"

Comment: But you can't have many SecondInCommand people, there is only one (or zero). Making it a collection isn't an accurate model of the situation.